# Why I free()ed chaintable's head the address of head and its next still exists?

Tags: c, malloc

I am learning chain table and start to write my code as below:

```
/*chaintab.h*/
#ifndef __CHAIN_TABLE__
#define __CHAIN_TABLE__
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#endif

struct grade{
    int score;
    struct grade *next;
};
typedef struct grade NODE;

NODE *create_chaintab(){
    NODE *head,*tail,*pnode;
    int score;

    head = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    if(head == NULL){
       return NULL;
    }

    head->next = NULL;
    tail = head; /*for there is only 1 node here right now*/

    while(1){
      printf("What is the score(to quit please enter a negative number)?\n>>>");
      scanf("%d",&score);
      if(score < 0){
         break;
      }

      pnode = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
      if(pnode == NULL){
         return NULL;
      }

      pnode->score=score;
      tail->next = pnode;
      tail=pnode;
    }
    return head;
}

void clean_all(NODE *head){
    NODE *p,*q;
    p = head;
    while(p->next != NULL){
       q = p->next;
       p = p->next->next;
       free(q);
    }
    free(head)
}

/*chaintab.c*/

#include"chaintab.h"

int main(){
    NODE *head;
    head = create();
    if(head==NULL){
       printf("***ERROR***:failed to create a chaintab.");
       return 1;
    }

    printf("+++DEBUG+++:\n");
    printf("address of head: %p\n",&head);
    printf("size of head: %d\n",sizeof(head));
    printf("next element size: %d\n",sizeof(head->next));
    printf("next element address: %p\n",&head->next);

    clean_all(head);
    printf("\n***Chain table cleaned***\n");

    printf("Address of head and next element: head(%p:%d)->next(%p:%d)\n",&head,sizeof(head),&head->next,sizeof(head->next));
    return 0;
}
```

I found head and its next element still exist after I free()ed them all.
here is the picture:
[image]
you could see that address of head and its next element never changed.

I have 3 questions:

1. Did I really release those space?
2. Why addresses still exist?
3. How to not let malloc allocate memory when chain table never have a valid value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking why `free` didn't automatically free the space allocated for some pointed-to things? Also, keep in mind that `free` is under no obligation to _change_ the memory pointed to; chances are, it's just telling the OS that the particular bit of the heap is no longer in use. Eventually, it might get overwritten, because it gets reused, but until then, it's probably not going to get changed.

Comment: at `create_chaintab` : `pnode->next` isn't initialized (last `pnode`). Should be `pnode->next = NULL;` after `pnode->score=score;` or before `return head;`

Comment: `p = p->next->next;` : `p->next` is not `NULL`. but `p->next->next` might `NULL`. at next loop of `while(p->next != NULL){` dereference `NULL`.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes:I don't know why mem address still exist after I free() those node first.

Comment: @BingSun So... you're confused about why the data didn't change?

Comment: function(pointer) can't set NULL to pointer. Because C is call by value.

Comment: the action free() takes is very implementation dependent.  Usually, it does nothing to the visible parts of the data you have because it doesn't need to; you've called free() to say you'll never look at it again, so changing it wouldn't be useful to a well behaved program.  Because creating and destroying address space with mmap or sbrk may be expensive, malloc creates arenas of space that it reuses.  You can check programs like this in a more strict environment by using valgrind or force the allocator to completely destroy it by using a page allocator (tcmalloc can do that).